# Wordpress get children pages in ascending order

Tags: wordpress

I am try to have the following function output all the child pages in array. Everything works fine expect place the order in ASC.

```
$my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page')); // This gives me everything

$my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'order' => 'ASC')); // This gives me nothing
```

I am new to WordPress and try to google for a hour, but I couldn't find out. Please help anyone.

Thanks

```
function get_children_pages_by_page_title( $page_title = '' ){

$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();

$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'order' => 'ASC'));



$page_title = empty($page_title) ? get_page_by_title( ) : $page_title;

$portfolio =  get_page_by_title( $page_title );
$portfolio_children = get_page_children( $portfolio->ID, $all_wp_pages );

return $portfolio_children;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this by using [**get_pages($args)**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), add your column `'sort_column' => 'post_title'` to sort by you wish to

```
function get_children_pages_by_page_title( $page_title = '' ){
$page_title = empty($page_title) ? get_page_by_title( ) : $page_title;
$portfolio =  get_page_by_title( $page_title );
$args=array(
'child_of'=>$portfolio->ID ,
'sort_order' => 'ASC',
'sort_column' => 'post_title',
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$portfolio_children=get_pages( $args );
return $portfolio_children;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody else need.
You need to Order all pages and the children will be ordered on that way.

```
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC'));

$children_of_parent = get_page_children($parent_id, $all_wp_pages);

foreach($children_of_parent as $child) {
  echo $child->ID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why @emilushi 's answer has zero upvotes. It just works.

Here is what I used:

```
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC'));
                $page_parent = wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID()); // Get page parent ID. Will return 0 for parent pages.
```

// creating a new answer since I cant comment yet.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could comment. Let me see if this goes through.